# Failed MySQL Replication (Slave is not getting data from Master)

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication

English is not my native language so please be patient.

This is the second time I had setup a Master-Slave replication with failures, most of other Q&A show some errors or similar, sadly my configuration finish "fine" but then doesn't replicate.

```
Master Server: Ubuntu 16.04
Master Database type: MySQL 5.7.19

Slave Server: Ubuntu 16.04
Slave Database type: MySQL 5.7.19
```

This is [the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) (which had worked in others servers) I follow, with some aditional steps:

1. Setup Bin days to 10. (on master) **(This is a database which cannot stop)**
2. Change bind-address = A.B.C.D (on master)
3. Set server-id on master = 1
4. Set log_bin and binlog_do_db (on master)
5. Restart MySQL service (on master)
6. Create replication user and grant privileges. Flush privileges.
7. Wait 'till 2AM and get Master Status.

---

8. Dump Database and "scp" to slave Server
9. Create database in the slave (same scheme)
10. Import database **(this takes about 7-8 days)**
11. Set server-id on slave = 2
12. Add relay-log info (on slave)
13. Set log_bin and binlog_do_db (on slave)
14. Change master host, user, password, file and position.
15. Restart MySQL and Start Slave

When I hit the classic "*SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G*", can see the Slave several seconds (465214) behind Master, but this time is getting lower. When this time get to zero, the horror, replication isn't writing nor updating. **¿What's missing?**

---

**UPDATE Jan 10 / 2019**

I just re-setup all the tutorial, and find the issue, but don't know how to repair it, `Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log` is all that the slave do, never `update`, `insert` or similar, any toughts?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
                  Master_Host: 192.168.0.54
                  Master_User: repl_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.013837
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 31260811
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000008
                Relay_Log_Pos: 1164406
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.013837
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: bd_caex_;
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1164193
              Relay_Log_Space: 31261278
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 684661
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: c2a462bc-3ffe-11e7-9b2d-1866daa42682
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

---

Example - `SELECT * FROM cx_retorno ORDER By retfecret DESC LIMIT 5`:

### Master

```
retcod      retdesc                 retfecret
294529205   2018-12-27 09:26:11     2018-12-27 09:26:11
294459995   2018-12-27 09:26:08     2018-12-27 09:26:08
294507948   2018-12-27 09:26:05     2018-12-27 09:26:05
294627475   2018-12-27 09:26:02     2018-12-27 09:26:02
```

### Slave

```
retcod      retdesc     retfecret
294453420   SIN MOTIVO  2018-12-15 15:29:58
294453421   SIN MOTIVO  2018-12-15 15:29:58
294453422   SIN MOTIVO  2018-12-15 15:29:58
294453423   SIN MOTIVO  2018-12-15 15:29:58
294453424   SIN MOTIVO  2018-12-15 15:29:57
```

Comment: How do you know "replication isn't writing nor updating"? The slave seconds behind master steadily decreasing to zero is promising and would imply that things are in fact replicating. Can you show us the output of "show slave status"?

Comment: @MarCPlusPlus, thanks for your comment. I know isn't updating nor writing because when I search some register cant find it in the slave, even when exist in master. (A simple "Select COUNT(*) from table" could be use as example)

Comment: @ElberCM Include an actual example.

Comment: @Petzy, thanks for your comment. Done.

Comment: Still can't make it work, I'm trying again on a VM.